# How to know which checkbox are selected if I have a number with the sum of all values checked?

Tags: c#, checkbox, sum

I have an existing database, and my table has a field in which is stored a value, a sum of all "values" of my checkbox list.

Another programmer made this method, called it "logic sum". I don't know this method, but now I need to know the reverse method, so I can know which checkboxes are selected by using the Sum value of all their values.

I really don't know how to do this ... I am using C# with asp.net, but the logic should to be the same for all languages.

Can you help me?

Comment: It is not always reversible, you may want to post the method so that people can suggest you a way to reverse.

Comment: Could it be that the sum is a bit sum, like from a Flag enumeration? Where the first value is 1, then 2, then 4, then 8, then 16, 32 and so on? That's the only way I know that a sum could then be split back out into a bit array. So that 33 would be the first checkbox and the last checkbox.

Comment: Yes Bill, you're right. Values are exactly like you say, How can I get the values involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally these things are done with powers of 2... The first checkbox has a "weight" of 1, the second one has a "weight" of 2, the third one a "weight" of 4 and so on.

You can check if a checkbox is checked by doing

```
if ((sum & 1) != 0) // first is checked
if ((sum & 2) != 0) // second is checked
if ((sum & 4) != 0) // third is checked
```

or

```
bool firstIsChecked = (sum & 1) != 0;
bool secondIsChecked = (sum & 2) != 0;
bool thirdIsChecked = (sum & 4) != 0;
```

and so on.

if you don't like binary math, you can go through an `enum` to leverage the `Enum.HasFlag` method:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyChechboxes
{
    FooCheckbox = 1,
    BarCheckbox = 2,
    BazCheckbox = 4,
}

int sum = 5;

MyChechboxes checkeds = (MyChechboxes)sum;

bool firstIsChecked = checkeds.HasFlag(MyChechboxes.FooCheckbox);
bool secondIsChecked = checkeds.HasFlag(MyChechboxes.BarCheckbox);
bool thirdIsChecked = checkeds.HasFlag(MyChechboxes.BazCheckbox);
```

Comment: Given an index in the range 0...n-1, `bool isChecked = (sum & (1 << index) != 0);` (1 << 0 == 1, 1 << 1 == 2, 1 << 2 == 4, 1 << 3 == 8...)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a company with 5 features (A,B,C,D,E)

**Saving..**

if(A.isChecked)

```
  features = features | 1;
```

if(B.isChecked)

```
  features = features | 2;
```

if(C.isChecked)

```
  features = features | 4;
```

if(D.isChecked)

```
  features = features | 8;
```

if(E.isChecked)

```
  features = features | 16;
```

Store features value in you db.

**Loading..**

Get the value off you db

if(features&1)

```
A is checked
```

if(features&2)

```
B is checked
```

if(features&4)

```
C is checked
```

if(features&8)

```
D is checked
```

if(features&16)

```
E is checked
```

Comment: A nice answer. Thanks for helping, Jodee90.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to work with [flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?
For this logical sum method to be reversible it must use the same principle as flags enums: each possible combination of checkboxes must result in a single unique number.

I'm guessing there are not that many checkboxes, numbered like this:
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32... etc. This way any combination will result in a single number, and the logical sum will be reversible.